# Changing variables on responsive breakpoints with enquire.js

Tags: jquery, enquire.js

I have a jQuery function which uses some variables for the "left-margin" value to create a carousel type effect on some inline divs (clicking an arrow moves the container left or right). Simple version would be something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/nX47z/

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    $("#carousel").animate({"margin-left": left}, 1000);
});
$("#right").click(function(){
    $("#carousel").animate({"margin-left": right}, 1000);
});
// Variables
var left = "0";
var right = "-400px";
```

How could I use enquire.js to change those variables depending on the screen size? I've tried adding them into the setup and match sections, but it doesn't seem to work - http://jsfiddle.net/mue9h/2/

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 1280px)", {
    deferSetup : true,
    setup : function() {
        var left = "0";
        var right = "-400px";
    },
    match : function() {
        var left = "0";
        var right = "-400px";
    },
    unmatch : function() {

    }  
});
```

I'd need the variables to be set both on page load and on resizing.

Sure I'm missing something simple!

Comment: Why can't you just use media queries in css ? It's pretty simple

Comment: I'm using jQuery easing for the sliding effect, amongst some other things, so was hoping I could do it with js. Do you mean to use css to animate the sliding effect (which would then mean I can use css media queries to change the left-margin amount)? Or have you something else in mind?

Comment: yes.What I meant was use media queries to change the value of left and right and do something like this: @media screen only and (min-width: 1280px){Add css animate on carosel}